# Android 4.4 and above version how to insert record in SQLite database on SD card

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-5.0-lollipop

I have to read and write to a sqlite database on the sd card (not in internal storage). I'm familiar with the sqlite pattern:

```
database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("mnt/sdcard2/test/temp/abcd.db",null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```

and I am sure "abcd.db" exists on the sdcard.

But I get the following Error:

> cannot open file at line 30217 of [00bb9c9ce4]
>   Failed to open database '/mnt/sdcard2/test/temp/abcd.db'
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database

This code is also working fine with android 4.2.* and below. 
I'm having this problem with android version 4.4 and above.

please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Android 4.4 you can't freely access SD card outside of your apps package directory. Follow the instructions from https://source.android.com/devices/storage/index.html and change the path on the SD card according to the example given

> For example, the app with package name com.example.foo can now freely
>   access Android/data/com.example.foo/ on external storage devices with
>   no permissions.

If you really want to acces the other directory use the Storage Access Framework https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html

Comment: okay, thank you for kindly replay,  but still i have one problem , my database file is  store at mnt/sdcard2/test/temp/abcd.db. and how to insert  data in my database.  how to use /Android/data/com.example.foo/ .. ?

Comment: may I copy file in /Android/data/com.example.foo/ at this location. and then after i use..?

Comment: You need to replace the com.example.foo part with your apps package. You can try creating an empty file in your app and saving it to the sd card - it should create that folder, then just copy your db into it.

Comment: okay....you mean database copy into /Android/data/com.example.foo/ ..   am I right.??     but one more thing this file is delete when I just clear app data from setting->apps->my application---> then after I just click on clear button at that time this file is clear.... m i right ?